# "Missing Service" When declare new Topic in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, entitymanager, symfony-3.3, phpwebsocket

I'm implementing sockets on my app, so I did these steps:

1. Create the topic handler service, like [this](https://github.com/GeniusesOfSymfony/WebSocketBundle/blob/master/Resources/docs/TopicSetup.md#step-1-create-the-topic-handler-service) but with an Entity Manager on his `__construct` method.

   ```
   public function __construct(EntityManager $em, ClientManipulatorInterface $client) {
       $this->em = $em;
       $this->client = $client;
   }
   ```
2. Register your service with symfony.

   2.1. The file `services.yml` looks like this:

   ```
   foo.topic: 
       class: AppBundle\Topic\FooTopic
       arguments:["@doctrine.orm.personem_entity_manager", "@gos_web_socket.websocket.client_manipulator"]
       tags:
         -{ name: gos_web_socket.topic}
   ```

   And **here** is when i get the error *Missing service* in the first argument passed.
   I can not found my Entity Manager but i have declared it in my conf file.

   ```
   personem:
       dql:
         string_functions:
           convert: AppBundle\Dql\ConvertFunction
       connection: connection
       mappings:
         GptIReunionBundle: ~
         AppBundle: ~
   ```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that im using `service.yml` when im in **local** enviroment and im not declared Entity Manager in my `config_prod.yml` file.

So i solved creating the entity manager in all enviroments.